# What console output commands are available in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

What console output commands are available in Erlang?

I know about io:format but was wondering what other output libraries exist.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For quick debugging, I find quite useful the [erlang:display/1](http://erldocs.com/current/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=displa#display/1).